# In OpenUI5, how do I get a target to load a new toolbar, but erase the existing toolbar?

Tags: sapui5

I have a small test app (just getting started), and I want to change the toolbar depending upon which area of the app I am in. At the moment, I'm using a Toolbar control. When a target instantiates a view into Toolbar, multiple toolbars are visible at the same time.

I have seen that "clearAggregation" : true should ensure that there is only one toolbar, but that config item in my target setup is not being honoured.

I presume that certain containers don't honour the "ClearAggregation" because of their intended purpose, so my question is which container should I use so that I can populate the area via the routing and navigation system?

TARGETS:

```
    "signedout-toolbar": {
      "viewName": "SignedOutToolbar",
      "controlId": "__component0---appframe--main-toolbar",
      "controlAggregation": "content",
      "clearAggregation":  true
    },
    "standard-toolbar": {
      "viewName": "StandardToolbar",
      "controlId": "__component0---appframe--main-toolbar",
      "controlAggregation": "content",
      "clearAggregation":  true
    },
```

ROOT VIEW:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="cpanel.controller.App"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
displayBlock="true"
xmlns="sap.m">

  <ToolBar id="main-toolbar" />

  <App id="app" />

</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

`clearAggregation` is not a valid property i think.

Depending on your version you have to use `clearTarget` or `clearControlAggregation`

if you'd have a look at the documentation:

> oConfig.clearTarget? **@deprecated since 1.28** - use
>   **target.clearControlAggregation**. Default is false. Defines a boolean
>   that can be passed to specify if the aggregation should be cleared
>   before adding the View to it. When using a sap.ui.ux3.Shell this
>   should be true. For a sap.m.NavContainer it should be false.

For more information, have a look [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Route.html)